# ADFS Login using WebClient returns HTML Form intsead of JSON response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, webclient, adfs

I am still in a learning phase of using web requests utilities and wanted to clarify this out. **I have created a ASP.NET Web API that returns JSON response and in order to secure this, ADFS integration has been implemented.**

While using WebClient I was getting the ADFS Login page as the response.So I used WebClient UploadValues to pass my Credentials with a Cookie Class.

```
public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
{
  var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
  request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
  return request;
}
```

Main.cs

```
 using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
      {
        var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "username", "" },
        { "password", "" },
    };
        byte[] response=client.UploadValues(ADFS sigin url);
```

**The problem here is that the response i am getting is an html form with all auth details and other parameters**

> that says Working.. and when I copied the html response into a notepad
>   and ran it inside a browser, it is redirecting me to the API url and
>   giving me JSON response. How to achieve to get the JSON from Console
>   Application.***

**Please help on this confusion.**

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ADFS are you using?

ADFS 4.0 (Server 2016) is the better bet since it has the full OpenID Connect / OAuth stack.

Also ADFS has to follow the protocols and you are following the Authorisation code grant. This mandates a login screen.

Or you can use the client credentials [flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-oauth-confidential-clients-with-ad-fs).

Comment: i dont know the version of the ADFS. From code i am able to authenticate but the confusing part here is the html response which i am getting includes this.
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></noscript></form><script language="javascript">window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 0);</script> when i am opening the html response and opening its authenticating and giving me response.